# Vercel Deployment Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, vercel

I am developing a React app in VS Code. I used create-react-app for setup. I can run the project without any problem with `npm start`. When I tried to publish the project with `Vercel` I got errors:

i commanded `vercel` in visual studio code. and work well. but occur error. cant finish deploy.

`Error! Command "yarn run build" exited with 1`

`Error! Check your logs at`

you can check log

````
Downloading 55 deployment files...
Installing build runtime...
Build runtime installed: 2.845s
Looking up build cache...
Build Cache not found
Installing dependencies...
yarn install v1.22.17
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@3rdweb/hooks > @web3-react/walletlink-connector > walletlink > eth-block-tracker > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.17.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@3rdweb/hooks > @web3-react/walletlink-connector > walletlink > eth-block-tracker > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2@0.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@3rdweb/hooks > @web3-react/walletlink-connector > walletlink > eth-block-tracker > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3@0.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@3rdweb/hooks > @web3-react/walletlink-connector > walletlink > eth-block-tracker > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime > babel-plugin-polyfill-regenerator@0.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@3rdweb/hooks > @web3-react/walletlink-connector > walletlink > eth-block-tracker > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2 > @babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider@0.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.4.0-0".
warning "@3rdweb/react > @chakra-ui/icons@1.1.7" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".
warning "@3rdweb/react > @chakra-ui/icons > @chakra-ui/icon@2.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".
warning "@3rdweb/react > @emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "@3rdweb/react > @emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.16.7" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > @3rdweb/sdk@1.42.0" has unmet peer dependency "ethers@^5.4.6".
warning " > styled-components@5.3.5" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
warning "eslint-config-next > @typescript-eslint/parser > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 32.62s.
Detected Next.js version: 12.1.2
Running "yarn run build"
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next build
info  - Loaded env from /vercel/path0/.env
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
./components/modal/coinSelector.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './CoinItem' in '/vercel/path0/components/modal'
Import trace for requested module:
./components/modal/TransferModal.js
./components/Header.js
./pages/Dashboard.js
> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your module import `./CoinItem` on `coinSelector` component. It seems like you have imported the wrong `CoinItem` path.

Comment: Ow. That's great.